# Is it possible to generate a part of data to liquibase inserts?

Tags: maven, liquibase

I have a large table in my database(61 columns, 318000 records). I'm writing an app using this table and want to test it. To do this I need to import data as insert statements to liquibase xml files.

I have tried this:

```
mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog -Dliquibase.diffTypes=data
```

Unfortunately maven says: GC overhead limit exceeded, because of OutOfMemoryError. I expect that it happens because of size of my table. My question is: is it possible to fetch a part of the data from file (let's say 1000 records) to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***could*** do it using Liquibase, but that probably isn't the best tool to use. Even if you did use Liquibase, you would be using a plain SQL statement to extract the data, and then you would need to do something to format it, etc. etc.

Better to just use whatever SQL tools you have available. If you are connecting to something with Liquibase that means you have the JDBC drivers for your database, so I would suggest something like SquirrelSQL. You query will look something like `select top 1000 (*) from tablename` You might want to add a where clause and and order by clause if those are important to you. Most tools will give you the ability to save the results of that query as a CSV file, and then you can use Liquibase to load that CSV file.